# Does np.save remove duplicates in saving content?

Tags: python, numpy

```
wiki_knowledge = []

for k in knowledge:

  wiki_knowledge.append(k)

  num += 1
  if num%500 == 0: # save periodically
     np.save(save_path + "wiki_knowledge.npy", wiki_knowledge)
np.save(save_path + "wiki_knowledge.npy", wiki_knowledge)
```

I am new to np.save() function. I am seeing other's code above. The array wiki_knowledge is accumulated and in the loop, how does np.save avoid to saving multiple times for the same element in the wiki_knowledge array?

Comment: It doesn't.  Each `save` is a full independent write.

Comment: @hpaulj So the above code is buggy since it saves duplicates?